# Independence of complex random variables

Tags: probability-theory

How is the independence defined for two complex valued random variables $Z_1=X_1+iY_1$, $Z_2=X_2+iY_2$?

Do we have $E[Z_1Z_2]=E[Z_1]E[Z_2]$?

Answer (score 1):

They are independent if $(X_1,Y_1)$ and $(X_2,Y_2)$ are independent:
$$p_{X_1,Y_1,X_2,Y_2}(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2)=p_{X_1,Y_1}(x_1,y_1).p_{X_2,Y_2}(x_2,y_2)$$

If $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent, yes.

Comment: So  $X_1,Y_1$ need not be independent?

Comment: For independence of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$, no.